# high-charts datalabel position needs to change when value is too small

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, highcharts, responsive-design

Data labels (in this case cash) appear in the right place, just inside the bar on the right, most of the time. However if the value of the bar is low enough, it ends up overlapping with the axis label (as shown by the purple bar).

My first instinct was to set a max value and change the position of the data-label base on that. Something like, if value is less than $10 place the label outside just to the right of the bar. But there is a big problem with that approach. The size of the chart is variable and responsive, so that threshold needs to be variable.

Ideally the bar itself should be measured and compared with the width of the data label to determine position. Achieving that solution has me at a loss. I have had no luck in getting the phyiscal size of the bar out of high charts, or the datalabel for that matter.

Thanks in advance folks!

[image]

---

UPDATE for Jugal Thakkar's solution on an Android 2.1 device

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the bar size, why not work with the div container for the highchart svg? That will give you a width of your chart canvas to work from, which would also work if the browser is resized.

Comment: because the condition is dependent on the size of the bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED AGAIN. Will work on all devices which Highcharts supporting.**

---

I think that [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/42dRt/5/) will meet your needs.

Comment: I cannot use a solution based on after the fact correction through `.attr` because the android version in canvas based.

Comment: .attr relies on SVG or VML where there are actual elements in the dom to manipulate. Android uses Canvas so there is nothing to .attr on.

Comment: @Fresheyeball did you try the solution on android though? I think the highchart wrapper hides the `.attr()` for SVG/VML/Canvas (not sure). Sorry don't have an android nearby to try this out or even the solution that I posted, so once you give any of the solutions a try, it would be great if you could get back to us with information as to whether it worked on the target device, or if not what was the behavior v/s the expected one

Comment: I have tested it. And it makes sense that it would not work with canvas as well.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I think that I've found a solution. Please try it out, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Fresheyeball did you tried that solution on Android 2.x device?

Comment: I tried it in the emulator, I will be testing it on a physical device later today.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I'll wait for the result.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding how you are made of magic. But it looks like you found the answer. Going to test it in my code and accept if its working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17154/discussion-between-fresheyeball-and-igor-shastin)

Answer (score 4):

You can change X and Y position using `attr`in the High Charts.

By, Default data labels gets plotted outside the bar. So, I guess you should have set X and Y positions in the `data Labels` property.

You can do something like this

```
function(chartObj) {
    $.each(chartObj.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
        if(point.y <=10) {
            point.dataLabel.attr({x:point.dataLabel.x+30});
        }
    });
```

Call this method once chart is loaded.

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/RzW8X/1/) for the reference.

Comment: +1 for the working solution, @Fresheyeball you may want to consider the browser compatability before going ahead with this, as it will only work on browsers that support SVG (read IE9+) @  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

Comment: @Fresheyeball, sorry my bad I was under the wrong impression that the `.attr()` method was an svg specific one, but its a wrapper by highcharts. So should work on svg as well as vml.

Comment: We are targeting iOS and Android, so SVG and Canvas

Comment: @Fresheyeball So did it work? If so please mark it accordingly or let us know of any shortcomings to help better

Comment: The problem is this: `point.y <=10` is not dynamic. I have no idea what number to put there. Some charts have a very high scope, and other very low. Also the device resolution varies widely so it cannot be an arbitrary condition, it MUST be based on geometry.

Comment: Also @JugalThakkar I can't make use of `.attr` because it won't work on canvas and android is a targeted platform.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
var alignDataLabels = function() {
    var chartObj = window.chart || this;
    $.each(chartObj.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
        var dataLabel = point.dataLabel;
        // Get the current X
        var x = dataLabel.translateX;
        var y = dataLabel.translateY;
        // If the goes on LHS of the axis
        if (x < 0) {
            // Set the label's X to 5 px more than the bar's height(length) in pixels
            dataLabel.translate(point.barH + 5, y);
        }
    });
};
```

jsFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/TCjJy/

Screenshot on my android  (Useragent: `Android 4.1.1 AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko)`

[image: Datalabels in android]

Comment: @Fresheyeball sorry? x<0 is if the label tries to go beyond the y-axis

Comment: Android 4.1 DOES support SVG. The most prevalent version 2.2 froyo does not. I have to support current down to 2.1.

Comment: precisely why I asked for feedback, this is the only device I got

Comment: @Fresheyeball sorrt for reiterating this, did the updated solution work on the target device? If not please leave a comment clearing that, so I can pull the answer out. Another suggestion would be add such important information clearly in the question as well as tags so that the right people can answer and no one's time gets wasted for solving the wrong problem

Comment: @Fresheyeball thanks for the screencapture, what I meant by "adding important information in question" was to add the crucial information that you are targeting android devices and hence most definitely want a canvas compatible solution. It is highly unacceptable that you reveal such important information after receiving as many as 3 answers!! Please take care of tagging such questions with an "Android" tag in the future. I know I don't need to be giving such advices to a user who is himself a good answerer, but wanted to get the feedback through to you anyway. Cheers you got your answer :)

Comment: I revealed that fact directly to you in the comments on the first answer I received. I will tag android next time and Thanks for your help and constructive feedback.