# Datalabel placement - Opposite of of chart data (positive and negative values)

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating a bar chart with positive and negative values and display the xAxis (category name) of each data point (See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bej8j/75/).

Here's what I have for plot options but I'm not sure what else I need (Really only putting this code in here because I need to include some code to link to a jsfiddle)

```
plotOptions : {
            series : {
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.x
                    },
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
```

I'm trying to place the label so that it's aligned with the start of each bar on the chart. I photoshoped my desired result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk1t5.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on each datalabel and use translate() function to move SVG element.

http://jsfiddle.net/eMjGg/7/

```
$.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

        position = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0);

        console.log(data);
        if(data.y < 0) 
            position-=10;
        else
            position-=70;

        data.dataLabel.attr({
            x:position
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you: http://jsfiddle.net/42dRt/5/

Here's more info: [high-charts datalabel position needs to change when value is too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487054/high-charts-datalabel-position-needs-to-change-when-value-is-too-small)

You must play with the X value:

```
plotOptions : {
                series : {
                    dataLabels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return this.x
                        },
                        x: ?,
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
```