# Pull HighCharts data labels to the right

Tags: highcharts

Currently, my Highcharts data labels are aligned to the bars:

[image: The current chart]

I would like to have the data labels aligned to the right border:

[image: The desired chart]

Any Ideas?

**Uadate**

Solved thanks to Pawel:

```
...
xAxis: [{
    categories: data[dimension].keys,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0
}, {
    opposite: true,
    linkedTo: 0,
    categories: data[dimension].value,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0
}],
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For chart with fixed width set for dataLabels:

```
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left',   
                inside: true,
                x: 390
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zf7te5ef/

If you have responsive chart, how about using separate xAxis for this? Like this:

```
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania']
    }, {
        opposite: true,
        linkedTo: 0,
        categories: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }],
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zf7te5ef/1/

If this is not enough for you, then read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487054/high-charts-datalabel-position-needs-to-change-when-value-is-too-small).

Comment: Thanks Paweł! I used your second approach.